# auto fired the text field once the value reach the certain length

Tags: javascript

Now I am developing a bar code based attendance system . Any there any javascript event can solve once the text field has detected the value has 10 characters, the text field will be fired and i can able to get the value.

Is there any solution ?

Comment: fired ? is there any code you have tried so far ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "the text field will be fired", but you can find out when the 10th character is entered by binding to the `keyup` event:

```
document.getElementById("example").onkeyup = function() {
    if(this.value.length === 10) {
        console.log("ok");  
    } 
};
```

It would be better to use `addEventListener` or `attachEvent` rather than setting the `onkeyup` property, but I'll leave that up to you.

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/NXMYE/).

Comment: So far, it can meet my requirement. but i have found out example as well. Here is the link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7105997/javascript-change-event-on-input-element-fires-on-only-losing-focus

Comment: @user1154655 - Yes, the accepted answer to that question is a good one. Be aware that it uses jQuery so you'll have to include it to use that answer as it is.

Answer (score 0):

you can check the length of the text input box value on every keypress and make a function call when its the 10th character.