# input change event triggered on blur

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

when I change the value of a text input and then blur that input it triggers the `input change` event again. How can it register this blur as an input change? is there a way to prevent this?

```
$('input').on('input change',function(){
 //do something
});
```

Comment: Related - https://stackoverflow.com/q/7105997/104380

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```js
$(function(){
  $('#onchange').on('change',function(){
    alert('changed')
  });
  
   $('#onEveryLetter').on('input',function(){
    alert('onEveryLetter')
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
onchange: <input type="text" id="onchange" name="Jenish" />
<br/>
onEveryLetter: <input type="text" id="onEveryLetter" name="Jenish" />
```

Comment: thanks for the code, I did not need the change part afterall +1

Comment: @user2014429 Just for note here Changed is equal to blur in terms of behaviour :)

Comment: One comment for mobile users: On Chrome mobile (maybe others), the `input` event has different behaviour, and fires on changes *and* on blur. I haven't found a way to avoid this behaviour yet.

Answer (score 4):

Simply remove the `change` event from your code. The `change` event is fired `onblur`, but only if something has been changed since it was last blurred.

Use:

```
$('input').on('input',function(){
 //do something
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Jenish's answer is correct. What's more... For those who are using a delegated listener like jQuery `.on()`, Here is an example that allows you to capture all the change events on the other form elements (textarea, select, etc) and ignore the change event triggered by a blur on text INPUTs.

```
$('div').on('input change',function(e){
      // This will keep the text INPUT from triggering for change event on blur.
      if(e.type == 'change' && e.target.nodeName == 'INPUT') {
        return false;
      }
      // Text INPUTs still pick up on the input event here
});
```