# Event listener for input's value change through changing with .val() in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling

I was searching the web for how to fire of some jQuery code if the value of an input inside a form changes if it gets changed through a script that sets it's value with `.val()`. `on('change')` sadly only listens to the blur of an input. Is there a way to get around this?

I want to listen to the form which contains many inputs, if something changes inside.

Comment: perhaps your code is wrong. We'll never know, because you haven't posted any code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javascript change event on input element fires on only losing focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7105997/javascript-change-event-on-input-element-fires-on-only-losing-focus)

Comment: The question is kinda what I need, but that just counts for event listeners that are set to specific inputs. I am having a form with many inputs and >I want to listen to that form, if something changes inside.

Comment: Can't you use jquery selectors to select all the inputs in the form? Something like `$("#formid input")`?

Answer (score 0):

Changes in the value of input don't automatically fire the .change() event. So, wherever it is that you're setting that value, you also have to tell jQuery to trigger it.

```js
$('selector').val(myValue).trigger('change');
```