# Facing unexpected behavior in javascript while checking string length

Tags: javascript

Ok, let me tell you my current scenario, I have a textbox in my page which accepts user input and if the input's length is greater than 5 characters then it will show a button.

Let me show you the code,

```
<telerik:RadTextBox runat="server" ToolTip="Enter your mobile number" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="mobile"
                                    ID="txtmobile" Width="70%">
                                    <ClientEvents OnKeyPress="openButton" />
                                </telerik:RadTextBox>
```

and the function,

```
function openButton(sender, eventArgs) {
                debugger;
                var mobileno = sender.get_value() + eventArgs.get_keyCharacter();
                if (mobileno.length > 5) { // if length of the entered text is logical
                    window.$get('<%= btnChkMobile.ClientID%>').style.display = 'block';

                }
            }
```

Now,
If I debug the problem I am getting expected result i.e button is showing up but 
If I press "123456" without debugging it does not show the button and after I press "7" i.e "1234567" it showing that button.
Why? How to get the expected result?

Comment: try changing your OnKeyPress to OnKeyUp maybe?

Comment: Try with `onChange`, instead of `OnKeyPress`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7105997/javascript-change-event-on-input-element-fires-on-only-losing-focus/7106392#7106392

Answer (score 0):

The `OnKeyPress` event is sent to an element when the browser registers keyboard input. This is similar to the `OnKeyDown` event, except that modifier and non-printing keys such as Shift, Esc, and delete trigger `OnKeyDown` events but not `OnKeyPress` events. Other differences between the two events may arise depending on platform and browser.

The `OnKeyUp` event is sent to an element when the user releases a key on the keyboard.

To understand difference between these keys read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3396754/onkeypress-vs-onkeyup-and-onkeydown)

> Replace `OnKeyPress` with `OnKeyUp` and your code should work.

```
<telerik:RadTextBox runat="server" ToolTip="Enter your mobile number" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="mobile" ID="txtmobile" Width="70%">
    <ClientEvents OnKeyUp="openButton" />
</telerik:RadTextBox>
```