# JQuery dynamicaly change value depends on input value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

I am trying to make change listener for input, it must set value to trans. field, when user type something to input field.

```
    $("#valueInput").on("change", function () {
        $("#transferredValue").val(this.value)
    })
```

But it didn't work, nothing happens. Script was loaded, I checked it through console.

Comment: Includes your html as well.

Comment: can you try `on("input")` instead of `on("change")` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript change event on input element fires on only losing focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7105997/javascript-change-event-on-input-element-fires-on-only-losing-focus)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below snippet would work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("input").change(function(){
    alert("The text has been changed.");
    $("#transferredValue").val(this.value)
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<input  type="text">

<p></p>

</body>
</html>
```

***`Another Way you could try:`***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#valueInput").on('change', function(){
      var changeValue =  $("#valueInput").val();
         alert(changeValue);
       });

    });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>


    <input type="text" id="valueInput" />
    <p></p>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! The second way worked for me!

Comment: That's great, pretty more other way also there actually,JavaScript is a fun I would say, you could try adding `event listener` or `keypress event` both nice.